syntax regions "contains" behave differently when included by another syntax?
I'm trying to resolve https://github.com/chr4/nginx.vim/issues/24, where Lua code embedded inside Nginx config is highlighted incorrectly:

I've managed to trim down the highlighting code to a minimal example, attached at the end.
The problem appears to be syn region luaParen parsing.

When I place the cursor on the first closing parenthesis (as in (10)) and run this command:
:echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')

It displays ['ngxLua', 'luaParen', 'luaParenError'] where the last one is unexpected.

When I place the cursor on the return word and run the same command, it displays ['ngxLua', 'luaParen']. I don't know how this is happening as the return word is clearly not inside any pair of parentheses.

When I place the cursor on the return word and run the same command, it displays ['ngxLua', 'luaParen', 'luaParen', 'luaParenError']. Clearly something is wrong with the opening parentheses.


I'm not familiar with Vim syntax highlighting, and I'd like some help understanding what's going wrong.
This happens with both Vim 8.2 and 9.1.

# vim:filetype=testnginx:
content_by_lua_block {
    ngx.sleep(10)
    return ngx.redirect("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ", 302)
}

" ~/.vim/syntax/testnginx.vim

syn region ngxBlock start=+^+ end=+{\s*$+ skip=+\${\|{{\|{%+ contains=ngxThirdPartyLuaBlock oneline

syn keyword ngxThirdPartyLuaBlock content_by_lua_block contained

" Enable nested LUA syntax highlighting
unlet b:current_syntax
syn include @LUA syntax/testlua.vim
syn region ngxLua start=+^\s*\w\+_by_lua_block\s*{+ end=+}+ contains=ngxBlock,@LUA
let b:current_syntax = "testnginx"

" Highlight
hi link ngxThirdPartyLuaBlock Function

" ~/.vim/syntax/testlua.vim

if exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif

let s:cpo_save = &cpo
set cpo&vim

syn case match

" syncing method
syn sync minlines=1000

" catch errors caused by wrong parenthesis and wrong curly brackets or
" keywords placed outside their respective blocks
syn region luaParen transparent start='(' end=')' contains=TOP,luaParenError
syn match  luaParenError ")"

" other keywords
syn keyword luaStatement return

" operators
syn match luaSymbolOperator "[<>=~^*/+-]\|\.\{2,3}"

" strings
syn region luaString matchgroup=luaStringDelimiter start=+'+ end=+'+ skip=+\\\\\|\\'+ contains=luaSpecial,@Spell
syn region luaString matchgroup=luaStringDelimiter start=+"+ end=+"+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"+ contains=luaSpecial,@Spell

" integer number
syn match luaNumber "\<\d\+\>"

hi def link luaStatement        Statement
hi def link luaString           String
hi def link luaStringDelimiter  luaString
hi def link luaNumber           Number
hi def link luaSymbolOperator   Operator
hi def link luaParenError       Error

let b:current_syntax = "lua"

let &cpo = s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save
" vim: et ts=8 sw=2

